# XAMPP, Node.js and port forwarding

Tags: xampp, portforwarding

I am making a multi-platform game which sends and receives data to my XAMPP server regarding player profile updates. And its a multi-player game so players are connected via Node.js and SocketIO. Can I make my XAMPP files and Node.js server accessible online via port forwarding? Will I need two different ports for XAMPP and Node.js? Is port forwarding a good idea or should I go with a professional shared hosting provider?

Comment: You certainly can operate both node.js and an apache http server on the same system. Two strategies here: either you have them listening on different ports or you have to place one "behind" the other by means of a proxy mechanism. For that read a bit about apaches proxy and rewriting modules: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: I do not really understand how port forwarding comes into play here... that would be solution if you try to operate such a server on your internal home network, so behind your internet router. If so, the question is not whether you should port forwarding, but whether you want to operate your server "at home" or in an operating center, probably by means of a virtual server appliance you purchase. For everything that exceeds purely personal and experimental purposes you do not want to go with a home solution.

Comment: port forwarding to make my PHP scripts and Node.js accessible over the Internet, not possible or not smart ?

Comment: That would mean you want to operate your server via your private internet connection, from within your private internal home network. That certainly is possible from a technical point of view, but it has a number of disadvantages: 1. network bandwidth is limited in such a case 2. network speed and latency is limited which might be a huge issue for a game server, 3. you open your private network to requests from the outside, that has privacy and security implications, 4. your private network connection is probably less stable and 5. you have to keep a system running all the time...

Comment: Oh, and I forgot the most important issue with your home internet connection: you most likely have a dynamic ip address which means you have to use a dynamic dns service to be accessible from outside. But still then you will experience gaps in time where you are simply not reachable from outside. A dedicated (virtual) system in an operation center does not have these disadvantages.

Comment: VPS is super expensive :(

Comment: Depends... I pay < 4 Euros a month, that's worth it for me... Especially since you get a separate system where you can install your own software and expect that no one sniffs your data. I run own email systems, an owncloud, various web pages, databases, calendars, encryption tunnels, ... But certainly a shared web space is less expensive. Cheap ones come for free, but obviously you cannot expect much from those :-(

Comment: got a great site they offering, $7/month, so I'm gonna get a Ubuntu OS there on VPS and will install Node.js and XAMPP. That'll do I guess.

Comment: < 4 Euros, :O whose VPS are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

i hope with "port forwarding" you mean on your home router, this is crazy, it depends on some variables, how many users can you support?,it's your connection good in upload and download? have you server at home? if the connection go down have you a backup?, have you the backup of data? etc etc, maybe the shared hosting it's better

Comment: users can be in thousands, connection speed is at most 4mbps, so a bad idea ?

Comment: but i only need to pass small strings, like http://myaddress/score.php?score=70 and then that 70 will be stored in database, but I guess might be tough for Node.js server. It will get so many requests each second

Comment: if you rent a server you have: high speed connection, good ram and good cpu where you can support so much user, low latency, and other benefit.